# UPDATE con SELECTs anidadas en Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, update

Tengo una estructura de tablas como la siguiente, donde tengo una tabla pats, que está relacionada cn otra pat_details a través de pats.id y pat_details.pat_id. Con 1 a n registros.

[image: Tabla pats]

[image: Tabla pat_details]

Y quiero modificar el último registro en pat_details de cada registro correspondiente en pats. Es decir, modificar todos los últimos registros de cada pats en pat_details. Y para ello estoy utilizando esta orden sql, que me da error:

```
UPDATE
  defaultdb.pat_details
SET
  dia_fin = 16,
  mes_fin = 5,
  anio_fin = 2022
WHERE
  id in (
    SELECT
      MAX(id)
    FROM
      defaultdb.pat_details
    WHERE
      pat_id in (
        SELECT
          id
        FROM
          defaultdb.pats
        WHERE
          patron_id = 13
      )
    GROUP BY
      pat_id
  );
```

pero me sale este error:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'pat_details' for update in FROM clause
```

Si alguien supiera cómo solucionarlo, lo agradecería. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Defaultdb que es?

Comment: Hola Javier. Defaultdb es la base de datos, y pat_details y pats unas tablas de esa base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación se indica lo siguiente:

> [13.2.11.12 Restrictions on Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html)
>
> - In general, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. For example, this limitation applies to statements of the following forms:
>
>   ```
>   DELETE FROM t WHERE ... (SELECT ... FROM t ...);
>   UPDATE t ... WHERE col = (SELECT ... FROM t ...);
>   {INSERT|REPLACE} INTO t (SELECT ... FROM t ...);
>   ```
>
> ...

Básicamente, no puede (directamente) modificar/actualizar una tabla y seleccionar de la misma tabla en una subconsulta (subquery).

Tiene varias opciones para superar la restricción, muestro un par de ellas:

Opción 1:

```sql
UPDATE
  `pat_details`
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      MAX(`id`) `id`
    FROM
      `pat_details`
    WHERE
      `pat_id` IN (
        SELECT
          `id`
        FROM
          `pats`
        WHERE
          `patron_id` = 13
      )
    GROUP BY
      `pat_id`
  ) `max_pat_details_id_by_pat_id` ON
    `max_pat_details_id_by_pat_id`.`id` = `pat_details`.`id`
SET
  `dia_fin` = 16,
  `mes_fin` = 5,
  `anio_fin` = 2022;
```

Opción 2:

```sql
/* MySQL >= 8.0.1 */

WITH `max_pat_details_id_by_pat_id` AS (
  SELECT
    MAX(`id`) `id`
  FROM
    `pat_details`
  WHERE
    `pat_id` IN (
      SELECT
        `id`
      FROM
        `pats`
      WHERE
        `patron_id` = 13
    )
  GROUP BY
    `pat_id`
)
UPDATE
  `pat_details`
  INNER JOIN `max_pat_details_id_by_pat_id` ON
    `pat_details`.`id` = `max_pat_details_id_by_pat_id`.`id`
SET
  `dia_fin` = 16,
  `mes_fin` = 5,
  `anio_fin` = 2022;
```

Aquí un [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ab0b5339a9e21e08c910beee816d99f) con ambas opciones.

Comment: Perfecto. Funcionó perfectamente. Utilicé la primera opción. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @evalde que bien. Entonces, selecciona esta respuesta como aceptada :-)